# Delete GoogleTag from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, google-tag-manager

I'm crawling a news website with the folliwing code:

```
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
archivo = open("News_Content.txt","w")
import urllib
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
links = open("MyFileWithLinks.txt").readlines()
i = 0
while i< len(links):
    conn = urllib.urlopen(links[i])
    html = conn.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    p = soup.find("div", attrs={'class':'single-content'})
    p1 = p.text
    p2 = BeautifulSoup(p1)
    archivo.write(str(p2))
    archivo.write("\n")
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
print("DONE")
archivo.close()
```

But when I print the news, the result is:

```
Some Useful Text .googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1417813885451-0'); }) More Useful Text
$("ul.social_media").clone(true).prependTo( "#redes-bottom" );
            });
```

I want to delete all the googletags. I've tried with replace but it doesn't work. Can you please help me?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract from the `div`? Can you give us an example of what `div` 's HTML code?

Comment: Sure, the text is like:    <div class="single-content"> <article class="text"> <p> Some Useful Text /strong></p><div id="adcontenido" class="adsense" style="width: 300px !important; clear: both;"><div id='di' style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;"> <script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-'); });</script><p> More Useful Text .</strong></p></p> <script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('ad4-movil-3'); });</script>
 $("ul.social_media").clone(true).prependTo( "#redes-bottom" );

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use [CSS Selectors](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#css-selectors)  and then use [`get_text()`](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#get-text) method on each of the objects returned?

E.g.

```
with open('News_Content.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    with open('MyFileWithLinks.txt') as f_in:
        for link in f_in:
            content = urllib.urlopen(link).read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
            tags = soup.select('div.single-content p')
            for tag in tags:
                f_out.write(tag.get_text() + '\n')
```